# MVC project database cant find

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner in MVC application development. I'm just trying to make a MVC application getting help from internet. That was a simple example and working properly. The article is said the database is in app_data folder. But actually there is no any database in that folder. Then I just tried to find the physical database location using the connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ePhoneBook-20140322204146;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

as the above connection string (I just not write down this and it is auto generated code in web.config file), the database name is "aspnet-ePhoneBook-20140322204146". Then I checked weather this DB available in physical location of the sql databases. My all other databases (My old projects' databases) are in that folder. But couldn’t find this database. then I tried with folder searching option in windows 7. There is no any database with that name. The wonder is my application run properly. Data saved properly. SQL management studio also not showing the database.

My question is, How to find the physical location of the database and why is this database not showing in SQL management studio.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're pointing to SQL server, and ,definitely, not to separate attached database file.

your connection string should look like this:

```
<connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ePhoneBook-20140322204146;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ePhoneBook-20140322204146.mdf" />
```

where |DataDirectory| - is actually App_Data folder in terms of ASP.NET.